# I can't my google font or Background header image to work

Tags: html, css

I realize this long but I'm at a loss for where my issue is as nothing is showing up right. I'm trying to get the Google font to take as well as the header background image. I've separated the html.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+Onexxx ');
body {
    font-family: 'Julius+Sans+One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

/*****GENERAL*****/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
header, main, nav, footer, video {display: block;}
body {font-size:100% line-height:1.5px; font-family: sans-serif;}

/*****WRAPPER*****/
 #wrapper{width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;}

/*****HEADER*****/
 #header h1 {height: 50px; background-image: url(../images/mountain- 
 shed.jpg); padding-top: 200px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; 
 padding-left: 20px; font-family: 'Julius-sans-serif'; color: #FFF}

 /*****NAVIGATION*****/
  #nav nav {border-width: 1px; border-color: black; border-style: solid;
 }

 /*****MAIN*****/
 /*main {border: 1px solid #000; border-top: none; padding: 10px;}*/
  #images img{height: 90px; width: 120px; margin: 20px;}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `font-family: 'Julius Sans One'`?

Comment: _“I'll post the HTML in comments.”_ - please don’t. Go read up on how to create a proper [mcve] instead.

Comment: your import has 3 x's at the end

Comment: And a space after the 3 x's.

Comment: @Pete google advices `font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;`

Comment: @Sylent I was more pointing out the `+` rather than the omission of a fallback

Comment: And a line break in the url of the header image. Maybe you should post the *actual* CSS. And if this is it, well, there is your problem. The developer tools (F12) should also show what resources are loaded and any errors you get from that, so that should provide you with some information about whether it's the url or the application of the CSS that's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used CSS prettify just for readability.

Your import had 3 x's at the end. As well as a space (not sure if it matters).
But here's your CSS, should work fine.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One');
body {
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header,
main,
nav,
footer,
video {
    display: block;
}

body {
    font-size: 100% line-height:1.5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#header h1 {
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(../images/mountain-shed.jpg);
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Julius-sans-serif';
    color: #FFF
}


#nav nav {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}

#images img {
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You are still using two different font names: `Julius Sans One` and `Julius-sans-serif`. This is the real problem with OPs code.

Comment: That's how google advices you to do it. works fine in my code tbh